# Using keyup in an iframe Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using keyup to do some updating on a timer and it works well.

```
$('.myClass').keyup(function(){typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);});
```

My problem is that I now need to do the same but calling an ID which is in an iframe.

```
For Example:

$('#myiFramesID').keyup(function(){typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);});

<iframe name="myiFramesID" id="myiFramesID" .... >
```

I've tried adding the ID of the iframe but it's not working ... is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('myiFramesID').contentWindow.onkeyup = ...
```

You must attach the event to the content of the iframe, not to the iframe itself.

Comment: How could I modify this one...as it's not working: document.getElementById("myiFrameID").contentWindow.onkeyup = function(){
    myFunction();
}

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? What is `myFunction()` and where is it defined?

Comment: It's not the function ... For example .. if I added: document.getElementById("myiFrameID").contentWindow.onkeyup = function(){ alert('hello'); }  ..Nothing will happen

Comment: Is the focus on the iframe window? Try using `contentDocument` instead.

Comment: Well it works on my project, although there I'm using `onkeydown`, or just attaching handlers in the iFrame's source itself.